# Haskell, String vs ...String?

Tags: haskell, types, happstack

I'm currently following the Happstack lite tutorial from their website. http://happstack.com/page/view-page-slug/9/happstack-lite-tutorial

Right now, I'm implementing the `echo` function, and the compiler is giving me an error message that I don't really understand. Here's my code:

```
echo :: ServerPart Response
echo =
    path $ \(msg :: String) ->
        ok $ template "echo" $ do
            h1 "Echo service"
            p "Giant, Haskell style Papagallo"
            p msg
```

And here's the error message:

```
src/motiondude.hs:35:15:
    Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM ()'
    Expected type: Html
      Actual type: String
    In the first argument of `p', namely `msg'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: p msg
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `do { h1 "Echo service";
            p "Giant, Haskell style Papagallo";
            p msg }'
```

I thought that a quote-enclosed "thing", like the

```
"Giant, Haskell style Papagallo"
```

was a string. Yet, from what I understand from the compiler error, `p` will not accept a string as argument. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The compiler doesn't complain about you calling `p` with a `String` argument. It complains about calling it with `msg`, whatever type that is!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you seem to have enabled the OverloadedString extensions which means that

```
"foo" :: IsString a => a
```

To coerce a plain old `String` to anything implementing `IsString` just use `fromString`. In this case however, Happstack has a function `html` which looks more appropriate.

Comment: Indeed, that's one of the two pragmas I have; well spotted! Does that mean I can implement my own "fromString" for any type I want? Is there also the other way around, a kind of "toString"? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you have `OverloadedStrings` on, and the literal is getting converted to an `Html` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the type annotation from 'msg', does it work?  That seems to be your problem.  On line 6, the string literal gets treated as Html, not as String.  However, OverloadedStrings only affects string literals, so it won't implicitly convert the msg (which you've said is a String) to an Html.

I'm not a fan of OverloadedStrings, but that's mainly because of the IsString ByteString instanace... It just bothers me so much more than the Integral Word8 instance, even though they have almost exactly the same problems.